# Laravel 5.3 failed to install Laravel Collective via Terminal

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, laravelcollective

I try to install Laravel Collective using this instruction https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html and I get this error. I'm using Laravel 5.3

[image]
Can somebody explain how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.3 there is no Route::controller that I use in Laravel 5.2 for users authentication login and logout . When I delete this in my routes\web.php problem was solved.